# iOS 6 SDK SLRequest returning '400'

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, ios6

Let me make this clear. I am NOT using the `Facebook SDK`. I'm using iOS SDK's `Social.framework`, and `ACAccountStore` to access Facebook accounts, and post with it/them.

I use the same code to post on Twitter. It works 100%. But for some reason regardless of what I do for Facebook integration, I get a "400" error when I try to post.

My method is:

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

// Specify App ID and permissions
NSDictionary *options = @{ ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"MY_APP_ID",ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends };
[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options
                              completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
     if (granted == YES)
     {
         NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message": string999};
         NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

         SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest
                                   requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                   requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                   URL:feedURL
                                   parameters:parameters];

         acct.accountType = facebookAccountType;

         // Post the request
         [feedRequest setAccount:acct];

         // Block handler to manage the response
         [feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
          {
              if (granted && error == nil) {
              } else {
                  NSLog(@"Facebook response, HTTP response: %i %@", [urlResponse statusCode], [error description]);
                  [self closeShareMenu];
              }
          }];
     }
 }
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong! It's so annoying! I've set up my app correctly in Facebook Developers and all! Please help -_-'

Comment: Sorry, didn't know it was so badly out of format.

Comment: What's in `responseData`? If you get a `400 - Bad request`, maybe you'll get some pointers from the response.

Comment: I don't know how to check what's inside responseData.

Comment: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

Comment: And what's `acct`? Where and how does it get assigned?

Comment: It's an ACAccount that is generated when the user chooses their Facebook account from a popup UITableView.

Comment: I have no experience with the framework, but if I had to guess, you probably should retreive an `ACAccount` from the `ACAccountStore` for which you requested access.

Try to get an `ACAccount` from `account` in completion-block.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I'm even trying to `[account renewCredentialsForAccount:acct completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult result, NSError *error) {` to get the latest access token. But still a '400' happens with:

`An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`

Comment: Ok, so not all code is shown then? Since I don't see an `ACAccount` getting retreived from `account` here.

The documentation says: *Each `ACAccount` object belongs to a single `ACAccountStore` object.*

Comment: What I was doing was archiving the selected account, then unarchiving it into an ACAccount object, and using that. Just grabbing an ACAccount object seems to work. Now to work out the rest..

Comment: I had to archive the account so it saves what account the user picked, over just grabbing one of them in an Array. It works for Twitter...

Comment: You could store the `ACAccount`'s  `identifier`. And use that to retreive the correct one.

Comment: Would you be able to assist me with that? I'm relatively new at this API..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22302/discussion-between-fguchelaar-and-cocotutch)

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?  I'm having the same issue with mine

Comment: I did, will be posting a solution in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Following up to the chat session held between @fguchelaar and yours truly yesterday; I was able to ascertain the following solution for this issue.

Add the following in your iOS completion handler:

```
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(temp);
//'data' is your 'responseData' (or another object name) that you declare in your completion handler.
```

This will allow you to see the exact cause of the issue printed to the Debug Console. Now depending on the issue presented, you'll need to grab a Facebook account from the Array of Accounts generated when you call this handler in the iPhone SDK. Not at any prior stage whatsoever, as the Access Token will likely expire and give you this '400' error.

In my case; the error printed was: `error:{'400' A valid access token is required…` which vastly annoyed me as my prior method to access and check the current Twitter account was working perfectly. And my theory was that it should work just as well for Facebook. Why should the access token be instantaneously revoked if I'm grabbing the account a split second before?

The way I solved my issue (depending on the reason for your error the answer can vary) was to use a for loop to check the newly created array of accounts, with the sole purpose of finding the account there with the same identifier string as the one I saved into `NSData/NSKeyedArchiver.`

```
for(ACAccount *a in arrayOfAccounts) {
    if([a.identifier isEqualToString:storedAccount.identifier]) {
        //set the account to be used
        accountToBeUsed = a;

        //don't forget to break the For loop once you have your result.
        break;
    } else {
        //This else{} block is not strictly necessary, but here you could set an account if no account was found with a matching identifier.
    }
}
```

For it to work, it's recommended to declare an `ACAccount` object in your View Controller's .h file, add a `@property` and `@synthesize` it, so it can be assigned within the `for loop` and used after the `break;` statement.

This effectively solved my whole issue with the '400' error. It was inexplicably frustrating for about six hours of my day, so I hope that my explanation helps anybody who happens to stumble across this issue, and my question here on Stack Overflow :)

Regards,
cocotutch